# join a string in each element of array

Tags: perl

```
@browser = ("NS", "IE", "Opera");
@browser =join("Browser:", @browser);
```

I was loooking

> `Browser:NS  Browser:IE Browser:Opera`

but shows only end of last 2 string . how to reslove this issue .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really want a map here:

```
@browser = map { "Browser:$_" } @browser;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use map instead to perform an operation on each element in the array.

```
print join(' ', map("Browser:$_", @browser));
```

Answer (score 4):

map is what you want here:

```
@browser = map { "Browser:$_" } @browser
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@browser = map "Browser:$_", @browser;
```

Or

```
$_ = "Browser:$_" for @browser;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$browser = join("Browser:", "", @browser);
```